# Show value on Mixed chart, Charts.js

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js

I have been working with charts.js for a couple of days and I can't get the values to display automatically on the bars and line chart. I am using a mixed chart and I don't really care where the values end up. I only need them to be there. I am very new to this so a full answer would be appreciated.

Here is the code for my chart:

```
 var chartData = {
           labels: Des_final,

            datasets: [{
                type: 'bar',
                label: 'Total downtime',
                borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
               showLabels: true, 
                borderWidth: 2,
                fill: true,

                 yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
                data: Total_DT_final,

            }, {
                type: 'line',
                label: 'Running Percentage',
                fill:false,
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                 yAxisID: "y-axis-2",
                data:Run_Per_final

            }, 
       ]
        };


        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            window.myMixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartData,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,




                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Operations Chart'
                    },

                    scales: {
                         yAxes: [{
                        type: "linear", // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                        display: true,
                        position: "left",
                        id: "y-axis-1",
                    }, {
                        type: "linear", // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                        display: true,
                        position: "right",
                        id: "y-axis-2",
                        gridLines: {
                            drawOnChartArea: false
                        }
                    }],





    xAxes: [{
        stacked: false,
        beginAtZero: true,
        scaleLabel: {
            labelString: 'Month'
        },
        ticks: {
            stepSize: 1,
            min: 0,
            autoSkip: false
        }
    }]
},
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: true



             }
                }
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a data mismatch issue, as in 'Run_Per_final' has a different length than 'Total_DT_final' or 'Des_final', I am just speculating

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please write speculations as a comment on the question (the button right under the question) and not as an answer. If the OP is saying yes that's the correct solution, then go and write a beautiful answer. Regards, Hille.